# What un-ionizes an electron after the photo-electric effect?

Tags: particle-physics

In an x-ray tube, the atoms in the anode are ionized by incident electrons "knocking" their K-shell electrons out of orbit. Following this, an outer-shell electron decays to fill the vacancy. Now:

> An atom remains ionized for a very short time (about $10^{-14}$ second) and thus an atom can be repeatedly ionized by the incident electrons which arrive about every $10^{-12}$ second. ([NDT](http://www.ndt-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Radiography/Physics/xrays.htm))

What causes the un-ionization, if there's another $10^{-12}$ second until the next incident electron arrives?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are making the assumption that every incident electron causes a K-shell ionization event. Only about 0.1% of them do according to your reference. So the mean time between successive K-shell ionizations is closer to about 10^-9 seconds or 1000 times longer than the mean time between incident electrons.

Second, you are ignoring the [space charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge). When electrons are knocked out they don't just disappear. There are lots of them hanging around and available to back-fill the ejected electron.